# Updating ResultSet with select query containing rownum

Tags: ojdbc

I'm trying to execute select query with table that doesn't contain primary key therefore I'm including row num in the select query so that the result set becomes scrollable but it is not updating and gives the error below

Java Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Connection con = Provider.getOracleConnection();
        String sql = "select rownum, users.* from users";
        Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        rs.absolute(1);
        rs.updateString(3, "Bibek Bhusan");
        rs.updateRow();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:955)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1169)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3368)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.UpdatableResultSet.executeUpdateRow(UpdatableResultSet.java:2690)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.UpdatableResultSet.updateRow(UpdatableResultSet.java:1835)
    at Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the rownum column and it should work. rownum does not identify a specific row. It's just the position of the row in that particular query result. Rexecuting the same query can return the rows in a different order in which case the rows will have different rownums.

Comment: Scruber: That does not help. I am also stuck at the same point. I doubt whether it is allowed to update a result set obtained from select query in which no unique key is used for filtering. (In another words, the SELECT statement must have a unique key in where condition). This is what I derived from running examples, can some one point me to some documentation that says it is true.